Civil war romantic movie about a girl, her mother and an enemy soldier
I need help finding a movie where a woman is left alone with her daughter, when her husband leaves to fight in the war (I'm pretty sure it's the American Civil War and they are from the South). Shortly after he leaves, there is a gunfight between the two sides in front of their house. The daughter examines one of the bodies closer with the young boy that lives next door and recognizes him as her father (but you don't find that out till later on in the movie). The mother finds a wounded enemy soldier on her property, takes him in and helps him. Various individuals come into the house, but they never see or catch the man. The soldier falls in love with the mother, but he is forced to leave for their own safety and to rejoin his troops.
Towards the end of the movie, we see a flashback of the battle in front of the house and see the little girl identifying her father and taking something from him, before the young boy from the door disposes of the body.  The mother asked the boy if he needed a hand, but he insisted he could handle it (they didn't want her to see her dead husband). Eventually mother and daughter are forced out of the house, they encounter a group of soldiers that included the one they saved.

Sounds like War Flowers from 2012 with Christina Ricci and Tom Berenger.

It is an American Civil War movie about a woman from North Carolina ( Sarabeth Ellis ) whose husband has joined the army of Confederate States of America. While her husband is away in war, a creepy neighbor is molesting her, and her daughter. In the skirmish on the family's farm, her husband got killed, and her daughter found him. She does not tell her mother, that her father is dead from fear that her mother would not take the news to well. They also discover a gravely wounded Union soldier who is using their cellar as hide-out. Together they decide to nurse him back to health and hide him when Confederate soldiers check the house. When the Union soldier recovers, Sarabeth makes sure he reaches his army. Upon his return, he is taken as a spy. Sarabeth runs out of food and the farm is burned to the ground, and she learns that her husband is dead. Yet, she is reunited with the Union soldier, and she decides to start a new life with him and her daughter.

Here's the trailer:




Thank you so much for your help! that's exactly the movie I was looking for :)
